# Difference between one column to many columns in dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
datetype=['Date received', 'Date sent to company', 'Date']
cols=[] 
for col in datetype:
   cols.append(col)
   for i in range(len(datatype)):
       if (col!=datetype[i]):
          name=col+"_"+datetype[i]
          df[name]=df[col]-df[datetype][i]
```

Date received, Date sent to company and Date all these contain dates. I was trying to find a difference between these fields. for instance, we have 3 columns date received, Date sent to company and Date. Then you will form 3 new columns containing difference of these dates by taking 2 dates at a time.
I am getting an error
KeyError: 1

I am new to python programming any help would be appreciated

Comment: To make your question clear, you have to provide example data and what your expected output is.

Comment: This will give you idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923775/calculate-pandas-dataframe-time-difference-between-two-columns-in-hours-and-minu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46222988/getting-difference-in-two-datetime-columns-in-pandas-dataframe and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143050/calculating-subtractions-of-pairs-of-columns-in-pandas-dataframe